# What would be the cause of server closing a connection before data was sent?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp-1.3

I have a cakephp (1.3.10) application that seemed to work fine, but recently I get an error page that shows "No data received" in chrome. This happens randomly on various pages and in various browsers. I googled the the error and found only unrelated information.

I haven't changed any code or upgraded the framework nor did we do any updates on the server that is running the application.

What could be the cause of this? 
Is this code related, if so where can I start looking to solve it in cakephp?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you logging PHP errors somewhere?

Comment: I am using cakephp and I am not sure if it logs errors like these. However I did find a error.log file which I am going through but it does not have the amount of info that I would expect for this error.
This file I found "app/tmp/logs/error.log".

Comment: This error.log file stopped logging errors 6 days ago. No idea why.

Comment: That doesn't sound like Apache's error log. It's usually in a directory named  `var/log/apache/error.log` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No data received" *could* mean

- A problem in the web server
- a PHP script dying due toe a fatal error (although I think a 200 should always be emitted... depends on the server configuration I guess).

If you're using Apache, check out its `error.log` first. Chances are there is something enlightening in there.

If that doesn't help, you could try [logging your PHP errors into a file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html).

Comment: This was a problem with the web server exhausting its maximum memory limit of 128MB in the php.ini . The apache error.log (after I found it) showed me this. I am little bit worried that just increasing it is a temporary solution, but that is a another question and research on its own.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens randomly it might be an issue with your script running into an timeout or using too much memory. I had this issue once with wordpress as wordpress sometimes calls an internal "cronjob" on page views from time to time.

Comment: I thought so initially after I googled it, but I get this response instantaneously, even before the page would start loading.

Comment: I was using too much memory on my apache webserver, but im giving the answer to Pekka since he lead me to the error.log and that gave me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case connection closure was caused by (AWS) load balancer that terminates idle connections after 60 seconds.

> **If no data has been sent or received by the time that the idle timeout period elapses**, the load balancer closes the connection. To ensure that lengthy operations such as file uploads have time to complete, send at least 1 byte of data before each idle timeout period elapses, and increase the length of the idle timeout period as needed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout

So if your server responds very slowly, reverse proxies can terminate connections unexpectedly.